# Using Components with .color changing the color sets it to the wrong color for whatever reason [Paper,Java,Plugin,Minecraft]

Tags: java, plugins, components, minecraft

I am using Paper 1.16.5 minecraft and trying to make a system for people to have chat tags.
It somehow makes the players name appear red instead of the supposed white

```
package de.zbinfinn.mining_game.chatstuff;

import de.zbinfinn.mining_game.Mining_Game;
import io.papermc.paper.chat.ChatRenderer;
import net.kyori.adventure.audience.Audience;
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component;
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class ChatRendererClass implements ChatRenderer {
    @Override
    public @NotNull Component render(@NotNull Player source, @NotNull Component sourceDisplayName, @NotNull Component message, @NotNull Audience viewer) {
        Component finalMessage = Mining_Game.INSTANCE.prefixes.get(source.getName())
                .append(Component.text(" " + source.getName() + ": ").color(TextColor.color(Mining_Game.INSTANCE.namecolors.get(source.getName())))
                .append(message).color(TextColor.color(Mining_Game.INSTANCE.chatcolors.get(source.getName()))));
        return finalMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone just explained this to me so basically the Styles are taken from the parent common practice is to just do:

```
Component.empty()
  .append(a)
  .append(b)
  .append(c)
```

Leaving this here for people that might need help in the future